# Are TensoRF's inputs not voxel coordinates?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, voxel

I wonder if TensoRF's code does not go through the process of obtaining the voxel coordinates for each ray.Is it simply receiving ray coordinates and performing matrix decomposition?

Please let me know if there is that part in tensorf code. Or tell me how to use voxel grid coordinates. Thank you.